# Number of Combinatorial Sequences

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of sequences consisting of *a*<sub>1</sub> - *ones*, *a*<sub>2</sub> - *twos*, *a*<sub>3</sub> - *threes*, ... , *a*<sub>n</sub> - *numbers n,*  which satisfy the following condition:
There is a *1* somewhere to the left of every *2*, there is a *2* somewhere to the left of every *3*, ... , there is a *n-1* to the left of every *n*.

Comment: What have you tired ? For instance if $n=1$ there is only $1$ configuration consisting of $a_1$ ones. Have you tried $n=2$ ?

Comment: If _n=2_ then, there are
$$\sum_{i=1}^{a_1} {a_1-i+a_2-1 \choose a_1-i}$$ sequences, where _i_ is the number of ones before the first _2_.

Comment: @user96160 Assuming $a_1 \ne 0$ and $a_2\ne 0$, then there is a closed form:
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{a_1} {a_1-i+a_2-1 \choose a_1-i}
&= \sum_{i=1}^{a_1} {a_1-i+a_2-1 \choose a_2-1}\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{a_1-1} {j+a_2-1 \choose a_2-1}\\
&= \sum_{k=a_2-1}^{a_1+a_2-2} {k \choose a_2-1}\\
&= \binom{a_1+a_2-1}{a_2}\\
&= \binom{a_1+a_2-1}{a_1-1}
\end{align*}$$

By [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity). An interpretation is that only the first element has to be a one, other elements can be freely arranged.